# Classical if else on a subset of bits in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Suppose I have a `QuantumCircuit` with three classical bits, and I would like to apply the `X` operation conditionally if the first two bits are `0b11` or `0b00`. Is there a better approach to do so than the two approaches I have listed down below?

#### Approach I: Each branch implemented separately

```py
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
c_registers = [Clbit() for _ in range(3)]
circuit.add_bits(c_registers)

with circuit.if_test((c_registers[0], 0)) as _:
    with circuit.if_test((c_registers[1], 0)) as _:
        circuit.x(0)

with circuit.if_test((c_registers[0], 1)) as _:
    with circuit.if_test((c_registers[1], 1)) as _:
        circuit.x(0)
```

#### Approach II: Create `ClassicalRegister` and ignore last bit

```py
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, 3)
c_reg = circuit.cregs[0]

# Ignoring the last bit by having same branch for `0` and `1`.
with circuit.if_test((c_reg, 0b110)):
        circuit.x(0)

with circuit.if_test((c_reg, 0b111)):
        circuit.x(0)

with circuit.if_test((c_reg, 0b000)):
        circuit.x(0)

with circuit.if_test((c_reg, 0b001)):
        circuit.x(0)
```

It would have been neat to have something as follows:

```py
## Approach III: List of conditions

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
c_registers = [Clbit() for _ in range(3)]
circuit.add_bits(c_registers)

with circuit.if_test([(c_registers[0], 1), (c_registers[1], 1)]) as _:
        circuit.x(0)
```

If there are no other approaches, I believe that the best approach would be to use write functionality to create the branches for the first trees methodically.

````py
def apply_if_cond(circuit: QuantumCircuit, regs: list[Clbit], bits: int, gate: Gate, pos: list[int]):
    """
    Conditional operator on circuit

    Inputs:
        - circuit: Circuit on which operation is applied
        - regs: Classical registers on which condition is applied
        - bits: Integer representing the condition
        - gate: Gate to be applied conditionally
        - pos: Qubit positions on which the Gate is to be applied on
    """
    if len(regs) == 0:
        circuit.append(gate, pos)
        return

    bit = bits & 1
    bits = bits // 2
    with circuit.if_test((regs[0], bit)) as _:
        apply_if_cond(circuit, regs[1:], bits, gate, pos)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
c_registers = [Clbit() for _ in range(3)]
circuit.add_bits(c_registers)

apply_regs = [c_registers[0], c_registers[1]]
apply_if_cond(circuit, apply_regs, 0b00, XGate(), [0])
apply_if_cond(circuit, apply_regs, 0b11, XGate(), [0])
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiskit allows you to add the same classical bits to more than one register.
So, you can add to the circuit one more classical register that contains these two bits:

```python
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
c_registers = [Clbit() for _ in range(3)]
circuit.add_bits(c_registers)

# Add a new ClassicalRegister:
cr = ClassicalRegister(bits=c_registers[0:2])
circuit.add_register(cr)

with circuit.if_test((cr, 0)) as _:
    circuit.x(0)

with circuit.if_test((cr, 3)) as _:
    circuit.x(0)
```

---

Another option is to use the newly added `SwitchCaseOp`<sup>[1](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.SwitchCaseOp.html), [2](https://qiskit.org/documentation/locale/pt_UN/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.switch.html)</sup>

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
c_registers = ClassicalRegister(bits=[Clbit() for _ in range(3)])
circuit.add_register(c_registers)

with circuit.switch(c_registers) as case:
    with case(0, 1, 6, 7):
        circuit.x(0)
```

Note, however, that none of IBM backends currently support the switch-case operation.

---

If OpenQasm is an option, you should go with OpenQasm 3.0 which supports bitwise operations and boolean operations<sup>[3](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/programs/docs/runtime/manage/systems/dynamic-circuits/Dynamic-Circuits-basics-with-OpenQASM3)</sup>.

Comment: +1 Honestly, I think that using SwichCaseOp is a really good way to do this. Better than my idea/answer

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in QASM (I perfer doing it like this):

```
qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str("""
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[3];
creg c[3];

x q[0];
x q[1];

measure q[0] -> c[0];
measure q[1] -> c[1];

if (c == 3) x q[0];
if (c == 0) x q[0];


measure q[0] -> c[0];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
measure q[2] -> c[2];
""")
```

For more information about QASM 2.0 : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03429.pdf

### Edit after the comments

This method can be perfectly done is Qiskit. We can do this perfectly if we dont measure the third qubit:

```
cr = ClassicalRegister(3)
qr = QuantumRegister(3)
qc : QuantumCircuit = QuantumCircuit(cr,qr)

qc.x(range(3))
qc.measure([qr[0],qr[1]],[cr[0],cr[1]])

with qc.if_test((cr,0b11)):
    qc.x(0)

qc.measure(qr,cr)
```

Comment: I believe this is also possible using `ClassicalRegister`, how do I do something like `c[0] == 1 and c[1] == 1` and ignore `c[2]`? That is what I desire :)

Comment: Honestly, I was trying and I don't have any good solutions. Also by the answer in the link i belive there is no option nowadays. Nevertheless, in next qiskit versions, we can do it for sure. Link : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/is-there-a-way-to-have-multiple-conditions-in-a-c-if-in-qiskit#:~:text=However%2C%20they%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20Qiskit%20yet.,with%20circuit.if_test%20%28%28c1%2C1%29%29%3A%20with%20circuit.if_test%20%28%28c2%2C3%29%29%3A%20circ.x%20%284%29

Comment: So the best option, for me, is using QASM. In this way we can say `if (c==3)` that means: `if(c[0]==1 and c[1]==1)` and with the method `from_qasm_simulator` you get the QuantumCircuit required

Comment: @Zeeshanahmed I have made some changes, it's the same but in qiskit and `if_test`

Comment: If you are dealing with 3 bit register, `if (c==3)` implies `if (c[0] == 1 and c[1] == 1 and c[2] == 0)` there is no way of skipping `c[2] == 0` in QASM either. The nested if condition is the best solution I guess :3

Comment: Im not so sure about that. I skipped c[2] because i didn't measure it. Therefore, it's not a problem if is 1 or 0. Note also that I made a Qiskit version